# Trying to determine the longest string in a CSV for every User

Tags: powershell, sorting, unique

I've got an CSV that got Created by a Script. This CSV has 3 Columns: “Name”, “Device” and “Program”.

Because this CSV is created by a script that reads out daily reports of the user activity, there are a lot of duplicates. I want to get the unique ones, but only the ones with the longest string in the “Program” column.

[image: Some Example]

I firstly tried to export rows with the longest count of characters but that didn't help me, because I couldn't figure out a way to sort for every user.

Comment: [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0) the CSV, [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0) by Name, then [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-3.0) each group by length of the value in the Program column.and pick the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ansgar's recipe importing,grouping returns:

```
> Import-Csv .\SO_54925782.csv|Group-Object Name

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    9 Mustermann,Max            {@{Name=Mustermann,Max; Device=ABC1234; Program={Test\Test\Application in use}}...
    5 Musterdame,Birgit         {@{Name=Musterdame,Birgit; Device=CAD1234; Program={Test\Test\Application in use}}...
```

Sorting per Program Length

```
Import-Csv .\SO_54925782.csv|Group-Object Name|ForEach-Object{
    $_.Group|Sort-Object {$_.Program.Length};""
}

Name              Device  Program
----              ------  -------
Mustermann,Max    ABC1234 {Test\Test\Application in use}
Mustermann,Max    ABC1234 {Test\Test\Application in use}
...
Mustermann,Max    ABC1234 {Test\Test\Application in use}
Mustermann,Max    ABC1234 {Test\Test\Application in use\Addon}

Musterdame,Birgit CAD1234 {Test\Test\Application in use}
...
Musterdame,Birgit CAD1234 {Test\Test\Application in use\Addon}
```

and finally selectig the -Last 1

```
Import-Csv .\SO_54925782.csv|Group-Object Name|ForEach-Object{
    $_.Group|Sort-Object {$_.Program.Length}|Select-Object -Last 1
}

Name              Device  Program
----              ------  -------
Mustermann,Max    ABC1234 {Test\Test\Application in use\Addon}
Musterdame,Birgit CAD1234 {Test\Test\Application in use\Addon}
```